# Retrieving JSON data from an Axios response

Tags: node.js, typescript, promise, axios

I'm using TypeScript to create a Node.js application and I want to retrieve JSON data from an external API. I have a demo version of the code I'm using, can't put my actual codebase up.

```
private async getData() {
    return await Axios.get(
        `http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees`
    ).then(response => {
        return response.data;
    });
}

getReleaseResults() {
    this.getData().then(responseData => {
        responseData.data.data.forEach((element: any) => {
            console.log(element);
        });
    });
}
```

The error message I get is: (node:6068) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined
    at C:\Users\Caoilinn.Hughes\OneDrive\Documents\TypeScript Demos\Azure Test Result Email Extension\emailAzureExtension\app\out\js\apiCaller.js:43:36
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
(node:6068) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:6068) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

If I don't have the for each and replace it with

```
console.log(responseData.data.data)
```

I don't get any issues. FYI the result set has a data property hence the "data.data"

Comment: looks like your `responseData.data.data` is not an array. Can you check what value it has?

Comment: see my answer. It should fix your issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are already returning `response.data` from your get function and then again you are doing `data.data` which would not work.

see this. Remove extra data.

```
getReleaseResults() {
    this.getData().then(responseData => {
        responseData.data.forEach((element: any) => {
            console.log(element);
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: The extra data is needed, if you look at the link you'll see it, the initial response.data is to get the JSON data from the axios response, the second data is because the actual JSON data has a data attribute, which itself is a list of JSON objects.

Comment: that is fine. In your getData you are already doing `response.data` and returning it. so that means you are effectively doing `response.data.data.data.forEach`. Hope it makes sense.

Comment: Thanks, actually still couldn't see that until there now, I've been looking at the same thing for too long. The actual REST API that I'm querying doesn't have a "data" attribute as a response, so this hasn't been happening there... Needed to take a step back to actually see the issue

Answer (score 0):

Add catch block to get the error if there is any. What is the expected response ? try to log it.

```
return await Axios.get(
        `http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees`
    ).then(response => {
        console.log(response);
        return response.data;
    }).catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Comment: The error actually occurs in the getReleaseResults() function, and the error I get there if I surrond the foreach in a try catch is, TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined

Comment: What was the expected response, did you log the response before returning ?

Comment: The issue was me not looking at something hard enough, because the response had a 'data' attribute and I wanted to access the JSON objects inside of that i would of have to access it like `response.data.data` but I actually had a extra .data that I didn't notice.